# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysqlpool'

Tags: python

Even I did `pip3 install pymysqlpool`. terminal told me `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysqlpool'`. finally, I got it. see my answer.

Comment: I said I even did that. see my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this at the end.

```
pip3 install pymysql-pooling
```

`pymysql-pooling` is one deps of `pymysqlpool`. but `pymysqlpool` is not smart when it missing some deps.